# Covert while loop to for loop

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, for-loop, while-loop

I'm trying to find the average of a list by using a for loop. I've done it with a while loop.

Is it possible to convert this into a for loop?

```
List_1 =[]

while (True):

     val_1 = float( input("Enter a number: "))
     List_1.append (val_1)

     if len(List_1)>=5:

         List_sum = sum(List_1)
         List_avg = (List_sum / len(List_1))

         print("AVG:",List_avg)

         break
```

This is what I've come up with:

```
val_1 = int(input("Enter a number: " ))
List_1 = []
List_1.append (val_1)
List_sum = 0
List_len = 0
List_avg = 0

for i in range (List_1):
    List_sum = sum(numbers)
    List_len = len(numbers)

    if len(numbers) >=5:
        List_avg = List_sum / List_len
        print (List_avg)
```

Comment: 1) Like `input(..)` was inside a loop, don't you think the for-loop version should have one inside the loop too? 2) `range(List_1)` is wrong. `range(..)` takes an integer; an integer that (sort of) says how many times you want to iterate.,

Comment: Use `sum(list)/len(list)` instead, it's more efficient than a loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
L = []
for _ in range(5):
    L.append(float( input("Enter a number: ")))

print("The length is", len(L))
print("The total is", sum(L))
print("The average is", sum(L)/len(L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking for the end of the list (a length of 5 in your example) within the loop, loop over a range of that length (a list isn't an appropriate argument for the `range` function), and print the result afterward. You don't need to use a list, either.

```
list_len = 5
result = 0
for i in range(list_len):
    result += float(input('Enter a number: '))

print(result/list_len)
```